# Grouping dates together by year in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataset of property prices and they are currently listed by 'DATE_SOLD'. I'd like to be able to count them by year. The dataset looks like this -

```
SALE_DATE   COUNTY  SALE_PRICE
0   2010-01-01  Dublin  343000.0
1   2010-01-03  Laois   185000.0
2   2010-01-04  Dublin  438500.0
3   2010-01-04  Meath   400000.0
4   2010-01-04  Kilkenny    160000.0
```

This is the code I've tried -

```
by_year = property_prices['SALE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(property_prices['SALE_DATE'])
print(by_year)
```

I think I'm close but as a biblical noob it's quite frustrating!

Thank you for any help you can provide; this site has been awesome so far in finding little tips and tricks to make my life easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. As you did, you can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert your sale_date to a datetime column. Then `groupby` the year, using `dt.year` which gets the year of the datetime, and use `size()` on that which computes the size of each group, which in this case is the year.

```
property_prices['SALE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(property_prices['SALE_DATE'])
property_prices.groupby(property_prices.SALE_DATE.dt.year).size()
```

Which prints:

```
SALE_DATE
2010    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dict = {'Date':['2010-01-11', '2020-01-22', '2010-03-12'], 'Price':[1000,2000,3500]}

df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)

# Creating 'year' column using the Date column
df['year'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Date.split('-')[0], axis=1)

# Groupby function
df1 = df.groupby('Year')

# Print the first value in each group
df1.first()
```

Output:

```
            Date  x
year
2010  2010-01-11  1
2020  2020-01-22  2
```